# how to replace the same value in pandas dataframe with a different value in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace value 0 in each row in the pandas dataframe with a value that comes from a list that has the same index as the row index of the dataframe.

```
# here is my dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12, 52, 0], 'b': [33, 0, 110], 'c':[0, 15, 134]})

#here is the list
maxValueInRow = [3,5,34]

# the desired output would be:
df_updated = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12, 52, 3], 'b': [33, 5, 110], 'c':[34, 15, 134]})
```

I thought it could be something like

```
df.apply(lambda row: maxValueInRow[row.name] if row==0 else row, axis=1)
```

but that didnt work and produced 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' error.
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you going to reverse the list before you use it to check the df? Your desired output is off from what you are trying to do.

Comment: my apologies, yes, the list needs to be reversed in this case. Ideally, I would not be reversing the list though and would keep indexing the same. is there a quick way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12, 52, 0], 'b': [33, 0, 110], 'c':[0, 15, 134]})
maxValueInRow = [3,5,34]

repl = {col: {0: value} for col, value in zip(df.columns, maxValueInRow)}
df_updated = df.replace(repl)
```

Result:

```
    a    b    c
0  12   33   34
1  52    5   15
2   3  110  134
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need:

```py
# here is my dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12, 52, 0], 'b': [33, 0, 110], 'c':[0, 15, 134]})

#here is the list
maxValueInRow = [3,5,34]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for column in df.columns:
    if row[column] == 0:
      df.iloc[index][column] = maxValueInRow[index]
df
```

##### Output

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 33 | 3 |
| 1 | 52 | 5 | 15 |
| 2 | 34 | 110 | 134 |

##### Update

As per your comments, it seems by replacing the values with the same index, you meant something else. Anyway, here is an update to your problem:

```py
# here is my dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12, 52, 0], 'b': [33, 0, 110], 'c':[0, 15, 134]})
data = df.to_dict()
maxValueInRow = [3,5,34]
i = 0
for chr, innerList in data.items():
  for index in range(len(innerList)):
    value = innerList[index]
    if value == 0:
      data[chr][index] = maxValueInRow[i]
  i += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

##### Output

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 33 | 34 |
| 1 | 52 | 5 | 15 |
| 2 | 3 | 110 | 134 |

Comment: Thank you Amirhossein, the code does the job. I thought something should be done with dictionary to solve the problem. anyway, I've decided to accept solution below which looks much cleaner. Thanks!